# How to add row after last row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

Table contains hidden template row and zero or more visible data rows.
In end of table there is add button which shoud add new empty row to end of table.

I tried

```
function addVariablesRow() {
    var t = document.getElementById("reportVariablesTable");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
    var x = rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    x.style.display = "";
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
}
```

but it adds row **before** last row to table. How to add row after last row to table ?

ASP.NET MVC4 application, bootstrap 3 modal, jquery, jquery-ui are used.

html:

```
<div class="modal" id="reportVariables" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reportVariablesLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" id="reportVariablesTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th>Calculate</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- first row is hidden add template row -->
                        <tr style='display:none'>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <textarea name="valuetostore"></textarea>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="totaltype-select" id="totaltype" name="totaltype">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Sum">Summary</option>
                                    <option value="Lowest">Smallest</option>
                                    <option value="Highest">Biggers</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- other are visible data rows -->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name" value="variable1">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <textarea name="valuetostore">a-b</textarea>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="totaltype-select" id="totaltype" name="totaltype">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Sum">Summary</option>
                                    <option value="Lowest" selected>Smallest</option>
                                    <option value="Highest">Biggers</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ... remaining rows
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    <button onclick="addVariablesRow();">+</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update

I ned to clone template row which is first in body and make new row visible.
I tried:

```
function addVariablesRow() {
        var $t = $("#reportVariablesTable");
        var $row = $($t.find("tr")[1]);
        var r = $row.clone();
        r[0].style.display = "";
        r.appendTo($t);
}
```

Is this best code  ? Maybe it is bettet to find template row as first in body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned JQuery is an option, you could use something like this:

```
function addVariablesRow() {
    var $t = $("#reportVariablesTable");
    var $row = $t.find("tbody tr").first();
    var $newRow = $row.clone();
    $newRow.appendTo($t).show();
}
```

Comment: I need that new row is empy. For this probably hidden template row should cloned and made visible. You code clones last row which may contain data. I updated question with code created based on your answer. Is this best code style ?

Comment: First row is table header. This edit probably clones table header. how to get first row in table body ?

Comment: @Andrus One more try... :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via jQuery like this,

`$('#reportVariablesTable tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');`

You can include anything within the after() method as long as it's valid HTML, including multiple rows as per the example above.

Comment: How to get html from hidden template row (first row in table) and add this html so that new row contains data entry elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = document.getElementById("reportVariablesTable");
var row = document.createElement("tr")
t.appendChild(row)
```

Comment: This adds empty row. How to add row from template so that it contains input ,select and talbeare elements from template.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reportVariablesTable').find('tbody:last')
.append($('#rep‌​ortVariablesTable')
.‌​find('tbody:first').clone())‌​;
```

Comment: This adds empty row. How to get html from template row (first row in table) and add row which contains input elements from it?

Comment: basically you want a copy to the end. then add the result of selecting the first tr. I have edited the answer to include what you have requested

Comment: Updated code does not add any row. Probably `clone()` is missing